# How do I get Autosize feature to show up for objects in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm brand new to Mac OS X development and to Xcode and the Cocoa framework.  I've been working through the "Your First Mac App" tutorial on the Apple's developer website and have run into a snag.  I've made it most of the way through but am hung up in the section where it shows you how to use Autosizing on the gui objects.  When I click on the slider(or any of the objects) and then select the size inspector I do not have any of the autosize items in the inspector window like it shows in the tutorial.  How do I get those options to show up?

[image]

Comment: What do you see instead? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: I've updated the post with a screenshot of what I see when selecting the slider and opening the size inspector window.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a new feature in XCode 4 called [Constraints](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/UnderstandingAutolayout.html). It's just an other way to define how your user interface should be resized when the window (or parent view) is resized. If you want to use the Autoresizing Mask settings from the tutorial, go to the File Inspector (first tab on the right) and uncheck Use Auto Layout.

[image]